# How Do I Store Objects in a Object in a Vector? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, class, object, vector

I hope this is not a stupid question. Basically I would like to access a string stored in a Class (Statement is the name I am using) in a vector of type Statement. Basically I am trying to store objects in a dynamic hierarchy of objects.
Types.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Statement{

public:
vector<string> Inner_String;
vector<Statement> Inner_Statement;
string contents;

void set_contents (string);
string get_contents(){ return contents;}
void new_string(string);
string get_string(int v){return Inner_String[v];}
void new_Inner_Statement(Statement);
Statement get_Inner_Statement(int v){return Inner_Statement[v];}
};

void Statement::set_contents(string s){
contents = s;
}

void Statement::new_string(string s){
Inner_String.push_back(s);

}
void Statement::new_Inner_Statement(Statement s){
Inner_Statement.push_back(s);
}
```

Main method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FileIO.h"
#include "Types.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
Statement test;
test.new_Inner_Statement(Statement());
Statement a = test.get_Inner_Statement(0);
a.set_contents("words");
cout << a.get_contents();
test.get_Inner_Statement(0).set_contents("string");
cout << test.get_Inner_Statement(0).get_contents();
return 0;
}
```

What happens is 
     cout << a.get_contents()
returns its string while 
     cout << test.get_Inner_Statement(0).get_contents() 
does not.

Comment: your code technically exhibits undefined behaviour. You cannot have a class `T` contain a `vector<T>` data member. `std::vector` needs a complete type. You may want to look at the `Boost.Container` library, they have some containers of incomplete types.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this piece of code:

```
test.get_Inner_Statement(0).set_contents("string");
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It calls this function:

```
Statement get_Inner_Statement(int v)
```

which returns a copy object (temporary) of type statement. On this object, you calls set_contents function, at which cease to exists at the end of the call.

Then, you call:

```
test.get_Inner_Statement(0).get_contents();
```

that creates a new temporary, from the unchanged statement, and try to get its contents.